# Float:Right images break out of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure this has been answered before but I'm having trouble finding a solution. This is what I currently have as my html:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="flip">
        <p>Click to slide the panel down or up</p>
        <img class="ux" src="/path" alt="complete" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
        <img class="ux" src="/path" alt="add" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
        <img class="ux" src="/path" alt="edit" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
        <img class="ux" src="/path" alt="remove" height="32" width="32" align="right" />
    </div>
    <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}  

#panel,#flip
{
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
    padding:50px;
    display:none;
}
```

When I try to put these together, images appear on the bottom right side of the div border, and then alter further when the `slideToggle()` is invoked. My end goal is to have all 4 images inline with the paragraph tag. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/4jNp8/

EDIT: Same JSFiddle, but with placeholders: http://jsfiddle.net/4jNp8/1/

Comment: Done! Thanks for commenting so quickly Dan!

Comment: Is that **all** the css? What's the class="ux" on the images?

Comment: Yep, that's all of it. The ux class was just me tinkering with it trying to get it to work.

Comment: Why the float:right in your title? I see no float in your code.

Comment: I was under the impression that the align="right" in the html was synonymous with float: right in CSS. Am I misinformed? Thanks for the clarification j08691 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to add `display:inline` block to the `p` and `img` tags:

```
#flip > * {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

`p` is a block level element, so unless you `float` it, `inline-block` it, or use some other positioning (such as display: table-cell) any content after it will not display inline with it.

Comment: That was...remarkably elegant. It's now aligned with the top of the text, is there a way to make it aligned with the center? Or do I just mess with padding-top?

Comment: There are a couple ways to do that as well.  If you *absolutely know* that the overall height will never need to change (i.e. you add more text to the paragraph, you're accounting for narrow devices, etc.) then you could use padding.  There's also flex-box (depending on your browser support requirements), display: table, using positioning and margin, among others I'm sure :)